# Windows 8 emulator : alternative way to run emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

i have search on Google that to run windows 8 emulator,CPU must be supporting SLAT. and my PC does not support it. so i am not able to run emulator. now in this case is there any other way to run emulator because  purchasing  windows mobile or new processor is not good idea. i dont have money for this.
processor core 2 duo
RAM 4 GB DDR2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While SLAT isn't required on Windows Server 2012 to enable HyperV, it is required for Windows 8+ to enable a rich graphical experience.

There are some details [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/q-will-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-require-processor-support-slat).

If you're developing a WP8 application, I'd highly recommend you acquire a physical device anyway for the best overall development and testing experience. Depending on your location, there are some very inexpensive devices.

There are no work arounds.

Comment: if i install windows 7 OS then will i able to run application in emulator? i am going to buy new windows phone still i need to use emulator for different resolution scenario.