# How to test windows phone 8 emulator without Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to create windows phone 7 or 8.  I installed visual studio 2013.  It came with windows phone SDK.

I have problem.  I have Windows 8.1 pro OS.  But my processor does not support Hyper-V platform.  I did enable BIOS settings. Even though i did not get this.

Any alternative way to test or debug app in emulator.

Any idea or suggestion should help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 emulator : alternative way to run emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264824/windows-8-emulator-alternative-way-to-run-emulator)

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate question's answer, your only option is to buy a physical device or upgrade your PC.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have enable hyper V from control panel also.

Comment: Not able to enable.  It is disable in Control panel(disable with gray color).  It shows "Process does not support Hyper V Platform"

Comment: does your processor support SLAT ?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx will be helpful to determine it.

Comment: HTT        * Hyperthreading enabled---
HYPERVISOR - Hypervisor is present--
VMX        - Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM        - Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
EM64T      * Supports 64-bit mode

Comment: then only option to test application actual device as stated by Microsoft "If your computer or your network doesn't support all the requirements for running the emulator, you can still install the SDK and develop apps for Windows Phone 8. You can only debug and test them, however, on a registered Windows Phone 8 phone."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative would be to test your app on an actual device (this does not require Hyper-V). For more information have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124554/alternatives-to-hyper-v-to-run-the-windows-phone-emulator).

Answer (score 0):

Not the most convenient way, but simple and it's working:

You need to register account at developer.nokia.com and follow this link http://developer.nokia.com/resources/remote-device-access. You'll find list of devices that you can use for testing your apps. Just choose one of them and reserve it and use it as you want! 
This video may help you to start:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-GbgPnTSxI&sns=tw

Comment: Please answer with your code and then link for details.